# Smart doorbell transformer issues

Tags: doorbell

I installed a new video doorbell and found that the exisiting doorbell transformer did not provide enough power.  I upgraded the transformer to a 24v40a.  When I check voltage at the doorbell wires outside I get about 25v.  As soon as I connect the doorbell and try and check the voltage I get a constantly changing reading.  I know that the doorbell is creating a load, but the reading goes from 3 up to 8 or 9, quickly changing.  The doorbell doesn't power on at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would guess your transformer is 40va. I would double check the out put voltage if you purchased a DC vs ac the power may be the wrong type .

Comment: Also, check the wiring. A loose or corroded connection, particularly if water-logged, could cause the issue.